# Ubuntu partition changes not showing in Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I have just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 from a boot stick I have made. I have done several different installs now, one where I manage the partitions myself, and other where I let the ubuntu installer do the work.

No matter how I do it, when it finishes installing, it runs fine. However, when I go back into windows and go into the partition manager the space shows as unallocated as seen in the screenshot:

[image: Windows Partition]

If I make ANY changes in windows to the partition scheme the ubuntu installation disappears. What I am trying to do is have a Windows OS partition, an Ubuntu one, and then a shared NTFS files partition.

Additionally, when I first tried installing I had a 100GB data partition as well as the ones shown in the image. In the ubuntu installer I increased it to 200GB and again when I went back into windows there were no shown changes in Windows Partition Manager despite Ubuntu showing this.

The Windows install is very fresh too so it may be I am missing some drivers, but just seems odd that Ubuntu reads different partitions to Windows since surely it just involves reading the MBR? Any troubleshooting tips would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have fast-boot disabled on windows 10?   Otherwise windows sn't reading any changes made to the disk when it's not running, but working on the fast-boot-cached version which can cause changes made to be lost  (windows will write over the updated-clusters with data it believes is up-to-date).

Comment: Ah this was the case, I did not realise it also cached the partition state thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Guiverc for pointing this out. The problem was due to the fast-boot being enabled. Turning this off shows all the right healthy partitions.